# Does breakpad's dump_syms tool handle gnu_debuglink sections?

Tags: gcc, objcopy, google-breakpad

I'm having a hard time generating breakpad symbols on Linux from stripped binaries.

I compile with:

```
gcc-4.4 -c -I../include -D_LINUX -m64 -fPIC -D__LP64__ -D_GNU_SOURCE -Wno-switch -Wno-missing-braces -fno-strict-aliasing -Wreturn-type -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-parentheses -pipe -fmessage-length=0 -g -DRELEASE -O3 -o lin/voxl.o voxl.c -fvisibility=hidden
```

There are also some C++ files.

I then link with:

```
g++-4.4 -o ../liblin/foo.so -shared  <objects> <libs> -z origin -Wl,-R,\$ORIGIN -Wl,-rpath,../liblin
```

And finally strip debug information into .debug files with:

```
objcopy --only-keep-debug ../liblin/foo.so ../liblin/foo.so.debug
objcopy --strip-debug ../liblin/foo.so
objcopy --add-gnu-debuglink=../liblin/foo.so.debug ../liblin/foo.so
```

The resulting binary can be debugged with GDB with full symbol information. It contains a `.gnu_debuglink` section which refers to `foo.so.debug` (no dir path), which is correct.

However, dump_syms doesn't seem to be following the link, [even though the code being edited in this patch strongly suggests that it should](https://breakpad.appspot.com/1644002/). I get this output in stderr:

```
liblin/foo.so, section '.eh_frame': the call frame entry at offset 0x18 uses a DWARF expression to describe how to recover register '.cfa',  but this translator cannot yet translate DWARF expressions to Breakpad postfix expressions
liblin/foo.so: file contains no debugging information (no ".stab" or ".debug_info" sections)
```

The resulting symbol file is 2MB, whether or not the `.gnu_debuglink` section is present in the ELF. When using this 2MB symbol file with minidump_stackwalk, the wrong functions appear on stack frames. When I run `dump_syms` on a binary with embedded symbols the output file is 9MB and stack frames are correct.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This turned out to be two things:

1. To load symbols from external files you must provide a directory path to `dump_syms`, even if the symbols are in the same folder as the binaries. e.g. `dump_syms foo.so .`
2. There is a bug in Breakpad that means external symbols will *never* be loaded even if they are found. [I've submitted a patch to fix it.](https://code.google.com/p/google-breakpad/issues/detail?id=626)